# What to do if asker picks answer that doesn't actually answer question?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

[On this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32489093/3525024), the asker's question was answered in the comments of the original question. They went around and thanked everyone for their comments, then ended up selecting an answer that addressed a different error in their code, which was inconsequential to the problem they were having.

I know part of the SO MO is the asker picks the best answer, but another part of it is keep the question as useful as possible for future users of SO. Would it be a good idea to flag the chosen answer?

Comment: It happens, the OP is not always the best candidate to pick the anointed answer.  That's why we can upvote the correct one.  By and large, they usually get it right.

Comment: Yeah. After posting, I had the feeling this would be a "It happens" kind of question.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Up-vote the good answer(s).

Down-vote the bad answer(s).

Move on.